# Why dict dont changing in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I have this simple code:

```
import random
from db import db

print('Simplest Database! H for help')

def p():
    key     = input('Enter key: ')
    value   = input('Enter value: ')
    db[key] = value
    print(f'Pair {key}-{value} putted to DB!')
    cli()

def g():
    key = input('Enter key: ')
    print(f'Key {key} is {db[key]}')
    cli()

def l():
    print('All database:')
    for k, v in db.items():
        print(f'{k} - {v}')

def r():
    print('Random value: ')
    print(random.choice(list(db.values())))
    cli()

def h():
    print('P to put data')
    print('G to get data')
    print('L to list all DB')
    print('R to random value')
    print('H to show this message')
    print('Q to quit')
    cli()

def cli():
    cmd = input('> ')
    if cmd == 'P':
        p()
    if cmd == 'G':
        g()
    if cmd == 'L':
        l()
    if cmd == 'R':
        r()
    if cmd == 'H':
        h()
    if cmd == 'Q':
        print('Exiting, bye')
        exit()
    else:
        print('Unexpected command!')
        cli()

cli()
```

And db file:

```
db = {}
```

I have two prombles:
When i type L, cmd prints database, yeah, but then print Unexpected command!
And main promblem:
**When i change DB, all prints, but file dont changes, and after restart file db is empty!**
I totally dont know why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you want "Unexpected command!" to be printed only if `cmd` doens't match any of the options, you should change all your `if` statements to `elif` except for the first one.

And you want `cli` to be a menu that keeps executing, you should consider change it to a loop. So you don't have to call `cli()` at the end of all your other functions.

And if you want to save the changes made to `db`, so that it keeps track of the modifications between code executions, my suggestion is to save it to a text file.

Since you are using a dictionary, you may consider the `json` package. Instead of loading your `db` from a python file, you can write down two little functions, one for loading and one for saving your `db`. This way you make sure that your data will be saved after exiting your menu.

Your whole new code should be something like this

```
import random
import json

db = {}
my_db_file = 'db.json'

def load_data():
    global db
    try:
        with open(my_db_file, 'r') as file:
            db = json.load(file)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        pass

def save_data():
    with open(my_db_file, 'w') as file:
        json.dump(db, file)

def p():
    key     = input('Enter key: ')
    value   = input('Enter value: ')
    db[key] = value
    print(f'Pair {key}-{value} putted to DB!')

def g():
    key = input('Enter key: ')
    print(f'Key {key} is {db[key]}')

def l():
    print('All database:')
    for k, v in db.items():
        print(f'{k} - {v}')

def r():
    print('Random value: ')
    print(random.choice(list(db.values())))

def h():
    print('P to put data')
    print('G to get data')
    print('L to list all DB')
    print('R to random value')
    print('H to show this message')
    print('Q to quit')

def cli():
    cmd = input('> ')
    while cmd != 'Q':
        if cmd == 'P':
            p()
        elif cmd == 'G':
            g()
        elif cmd == 'L':
            l()
        elif cmd == 'R':
            r()
        elif cmd == 'H':
            h()
        else:
            print('Unexpected command!')
        cmd = input('> ')
    else:
        print('Exiting, bye')
        save_data()
        exit()


print('Simplest Database! H for help')
load_data()
cli()
```

It's pretty much the same, I've just done the corrections to `cli`, removed its call from the other functions since it's not necessary anymore, and added the two new functions for saving and loading your data.

After running this code for the first time, you'll notice a new file called `db.json` in the same directory of your python script. It's your database, you may look into it if you want to check if the data is stored as you wanted.

That's it. Let us know if you have any further questions!